# Cannot add any taglib to JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

Hey I am trying to add a taglib for example

to my javascript file however it doesn't compile. Is it possible to use spring:message class in javascript file?

It works when the javascript is in JSP when it is in Javascript file it doesn't. I guess there is no way I can use spring messages in JavaScript. Anyway to do it?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSP is compiled to a java code by a special jsp compiler, that is afterwards comipled to bytecode. During th compile process the taglib is evaluated. This does not happen to your JavaScript file and that is the reason why you can not use a taglib outside of a jsp.